# Postgres DISTINCT to single row

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to DISTINCT to single row

here is my code:

```
SELECT 
wagon.name w_name,
'' as su_name,
'' as m_name,
'' as sk_name,
'' as p_name,
'' as b_name,
'' as o_name,
total w_total,
0 as su_total,
0 as m_total,
0 as sk_total,
0 as p_total,
0 as b_total,
0 as o_total

FROM wagoning 
LEFT JOIN wagon ON wagoning.wagon_id = wagon.id 

UNION ALL

SELECT 

'' w_name,
name su_name,
'' m_name,
'' sk_name,
'' p_name,
'' b_name,
'' o_name,
0 w_total,
total su_total,
0 m_total,
0 sk_total,
0 p_total,
0 b_total,
0 o_total

FROM drying 
LEFT JOIN drier ON drying.drier_id = drier.id 

UNION ALL

SELECT 

'' w_name,
'' su_name,
quantity::varchar as m_name,
'' sk_name,
'' p_name,
'' b_name,
'' o_name,
0 w_total,
0 su_total,
total m_total,
0 sk_total,
0 p_total,
0 b_total,
0 o_total

FROM
bagging

UNION ALL

SELECT 

'' w_name,
'' su_name,
'' m_name,
quantity::varchar as sk_name,
'' p_name,
'' b_name,
'' o_name,
0 w_total,
0 su_total,
0 m_total,
total sk_total,
0 p_total,
0 b_total,
0 o_total


FROM
storing

UNION ALL

SELECT 

'' w_name,
'' su_name,
'' m_name,
'' sk_name,
quantity::varchar as p_name,
'' b_name,
'' o_name,
0 w_total,
0 su_total,
0 m_total,
0 sk_total,
total p_total,
0 b_total,
0 o_total

FROM
processing

UNION ALL

SELECT 

'' w_name,
'' su_name,
'' m_name,
'' sk_name,
'' p_name,
quantity::varchar as b_name,
'' o_name,
0 w_total,
0 su_total,
0 m_total,
0 sk_total,
0 p_total,
quantity * net b_total,
0 o_total

FROM
boxing

UNION ALL

SELECT 

'' w_name,
'' su_name,
'' m_name,
'' sk_name,
'' p_name,
'' b_name,
'' o_name,
0 w_total,
0 su_total,
0 m_total,
0 sk_total,
0 p_total,
0 b_total,
part o_total

FROM
boxing
```

Please check the screenshot below: top result (above the red) how it is working now. What I want is below the red line as in single row

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zss2X.jpg)

Comment: Please don't add images. Please add your ouput and expected output to the question as text.

Comment: Please attach your schema of DB

Comment: StackOverflow thanks you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want `MAX` over the query result of all `UNION ALL`

```
select MAX(w_name) as w_name,
       MAX(su_name)as su_name,
      -- ..  other columns

FROM
(
SELECT 
wagon.name w_name,
'' as su_name,
'' as m_name,
'' as sk_name,
'' as p_name,
'' as b_name,
'' as o_name,
total w_total,
0 as su_total,
0 as m_total,
0 as sk_total,
0 as p_total,
0 as b_total,
0 as o_total

FROM wagoning 
LEFT JOIN wagon ON wagoning.wagon_id = wagon.id 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
..
```

Comment: Can't use max. It should be repeater in Ireport

Comment: @MaratRaimberdievich : But, I don't see that in your query, it has always only one non-null column per query

Comment: I tried but it didnt work on repeater. it shows only one row always. I need to repeat those tables as one row, and repeat for other records. Well a client wants those shitty reports :(

Comment: Well jasper iReport does the repeating part. I just give a row it will repeat for other records.